# Grid View Pagination

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ado.net, pagination

I have a `GridView`, and I want to implement Pagination functionality.  This is working fine.

```
protected DataSet FillDataSet()
{
    string source = "Database=GridTest;Server=Localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes";
    con = new SqlConnection(source);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_mygrid", con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    return ds;


}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   int newPagenumber = e.NewPageIndex;
   GridView1.PageIndex = newPagenumber;
   GridView1.DataSource = FillDataSet();
   GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

But the problem is for each pagination I have to call `FillDataSet();`.  Is there any way to stop that.  Any other coding approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Scott Mitchell's article: [Custom Paging in ASP.NET 2.0 with SQL Server 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx).

If you're using a version of SQL Server pre-2005, then try: [A More Efficient Method for Paging Through Large Result Sets](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using [LINQ To SQL as it makes it easy to implement server-side pagingation](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=267).