# SqlDataAdapter memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, sqldataadapter

I have an application which loads 1500,000 to a grid. Issue is it takes lots of memory. (1.8 GB)

I observed following,

- Same query if I run on SQL Query
  Analyzer it takes around 60MB
- In application if I just execute
  ExecuteNonQuery() it also takes
  somewhere around 60MB.

Issue comes when I execute it to get output as DataTable, I feel there is some issue in the way I do it. Please help.

Here's the way I do it, (even though I call a SP, it too execute the sql which I pass as a parameter)

```
                    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                    {
                        SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                        //DbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                        command.CommandTimeout = 30000;
                        conn.Open();
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command.CommandText = spName;
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                        dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        if (dt != null)
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                            {
                                dt = null;
                            }
                        }
                        conn.Close();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem when loading up a lot of data from text files into datatables/datagrids. A lot of the data I am loading cannot easily be typed as the files come from many different sources with many variations, so they are all simply loaded in as text columns. A lot of the data I am loading is simply one character long

[This article](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/jcrease/archive/2009/01/16/71678.aspx) discusses the overhead of strings in .NET and the effect this has on lots of elements of just one character. It provides examples using ANTs profiler. I got the trial version and used it to confirm the usage I was seeing. Due to the variations in the data I had, I couldn't adjust my column types, but if you find you have columns of data that can by typed as something other than string, then you might find some significant improvements.

Comment: What sort of data are you loading up? Is it numeric, string, datetime or a combination of all? If you are loading 1.5 Million records from a database into a datatable, it is likely going to cause quite a bit of memory usage. As Boas states, investing some time in pagination will mean that you won't have to load the entire 1.5 million rows at one time and will save a considerable amount of memory. It will just mean that you hit the database more often to get a new set of results.

Comment: Moose, correct it is mix of data types. I am loading all the records to DataTable then to DataGrid to show them. Paging can be implemented when we scroll if application can load it. Do you know a feasible way to implement ?

Comment: Sure. Nothing that can be answered in a SO comment though. The basic idea is to only retrieve the required number of records to be displayed at any one time. So you if you are only showing 50 records then you can simply retrieve the required 50, and then on a click of the second page, grab the next 50 to be displayed. Take a look at other SO posts like <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248447/grid-view-pagination> or try pagination gridview in Google for some tutorials etc. Best of luck. This will certainly reduce the impact of memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can implement somekind of paging or "load on demand" ?

When running this method twice, you dispose the old datatable, don't you ?

Comment: I am loading result set to a DataGridView, how to use paging there ?